# facebook graph api getting only one picture in feeds

Tags: php, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I am developing an app using the facebook graph api.
When I create an album with more than three pictures on facebook, on my wall post it displays three thumbnail images, but when I check in the feeds in the graph api, it only gives link to one image.

I checked out similar websites, and they also display three images like facebook not sure how to do this.

Comment: Do the images get displayed in **one** feed? or **three** feeds? and can you show us some code? the response of your graph api, how you are calling it...etc

Comment: Please check: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/ on this page, click on "News feed:" link, this is the same as displayed in your facebook home page. but, if you created a new album, you will see three pictures in your facebook home page, and only one in the graph api feed.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this problem ?if yes please share..

Comment: No perfect solution, but I took up the album id and kept a request to fetch all the pictures in the album and than displayed the first three.

Comment: To develop for facebook is difficult!

Answer (score -1):

I think you are supposed to get the photos uploaded in a particular album,for that you can use
    https://graph.facebook.com/facebook_d/albums
    this will return all album details with album_id,using that album id you can fetch the photos in that album by
    https://graph.facebook.com/album_id/photos.

Comment: We are talking about the feeds api, which returns only 1 picture while on facebook.com there are three. A separate request has to be kept to fetch more pictures.